# VS 2017 Dataset Designer operations extremely slow (not just save)

Tags: dataset, visual-studio-2017, designer, devart, dotconnect

I’m using Visual Studio 2017 to manage a large dataset, which until recently, was working fine.  Now I’m experiencing excessive wait times for several Dataset Designer operations.

I’m using:

- Visual Studio 2017 (v15.5.1)
- PostreSQL 9.3 (running locally)
- DevArt dotConnect PostgreSQL (version 7.9.931.0)
- Database contains: 250 tables / 1000 views / 750 stored procedures

The problems I’m seeing are:

1. After first opening the Dataset Designer, a Preview operation on a simple TableAdapter (connected to a small table) takes 3 minutes.  The second preview of the same TableAdapter returns data within a second.  After the first preview delay, all TableAdapters return data quickly.  This same operation used to take less than a second.
2. When adding a new TableAdapter, and choosing the Query Builder, the operations of returning a list of tables and views takes much longer than it used to.  This delay occurs every time, not just the first time.
3. When adding a new TableAdapter, and choosing the Use existing stored procedures option, it takes roughly 1 minute to return a list of available stored procedures in the database.  This used to take no more than 3 seconds.   This delay occurs every time, not just the first time.
4. Modifying and saving existing TableAdapter also now takes minutes instead of seconds.

Here’s what I’ve done so far with no change:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2017 (15.5.1)
- Uninstalled and reinstalled DevArt dotConnect PostgreSQL (version 7.9.931.0)
- Connected to another PostgreSQL instance hosted on a server

During all the above delays, Task Manager shows the devenv.exe process running at a consistent 8% CPU.  My machine has plenty of physical memory available (over 50%).  The Resource Monitor shows devenv.exe as Not Responding.

I running out of options.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please contact us via https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html.

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing your `%temp% folder`. It worked for me.